# Optimization problem with different type of constraints

Tags: python, optimization, matlab, objective-function, linear-programming

I'm new to optimization problems. I want to find optimum values for my objective function. You can imagine my function as `E = f(t1, t2, t3)`. I want to minimize `E` and following constraints limit the variables:
**1**- 0 < t1, t2, t3 < 255 
**2**- t1, t2, and t3 be less as possible
**3**- being `zero` for one of this parameters is more important than overall values be low. for example (80, 150, 0) is better than (140, 50, 20) because first set of parameters have `zero`. Note that nature of `E` almost reacts as mentioned. However, I want to limit parameters as mentioned if it is possible.

Is there algorithm for such problems? I read optimization in this [linear programming example of Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/example-linear-programming-via-problem.html) but I can't find constraints mentioned in **2** and **3**. Any help using `Matlab` or `Python 3.X` will be appreciated.